Query not returning the OldValue and NewValue Fields on accounthistory object
I have a very simple query below, it works perfect other than it does not return the OldValue and New Value Fields.  It runs and returns all expected results but does not include these two fields.  So I am able to tell when a change was made but not the old and new values.
'''SELECT AccountId,Field,NewValue,OldValue ,CreatedDate
FROM AccountHistory
WHERE accountid = '0011S00000e2nQoQAI' '''

Where are you executing this query?  In Developer Console, the old Developer Workbench site, or some other way?  I ask because the old Developer Workbench definitely has problems with displaying OldValue/NewValue fields in a soql query.

I am using dbeaver and connecting to SF backend,  I also tried it in workbench with same result but in Dev console it does return the expected values.

Try putting the value fields first in the SOQL statement, e.g. SELECT OldValue, NewValue, ... FROM AccountHistory .... That's what you have to do in Dev Workbench.

Please verify whether you have activated the history tracking feature with the options for tracking both old and new values. If you have only selected the 'Track changes only' option, the changes will not be visible. Typically, text areas are tracked as changes but do not display old and new values. For further details, refer to the Salesforce help documentation.
SF Help



I double checked that we are including the field as old and new and not just tracking.  I can also see the old and new value field populating in Salesforce report.  Its just when I query the data via SOQL that it does not appear.
